# GUID lookup in table fails when culture is set to "Danish"

Tags: vb.net, cultureinfo

```
Dim ii = _DsAttribute.Tables(0).Rows.Find(Convert.ToString(DtgFields.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("AttributeID").Value, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")))  '.ToString.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
Dim jj = _DsAttribute.Tables(0).Rows.Find(Convert.ToString(DtgFields.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("AttributeID").Value, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))).Item("Checked")
```

I tried many variations of the above, trying to keep the database's data from being "corrupted" by my machine's Danish culture (set in region/language settings in Windows). I tried invariant culture, fr-FR and en-US.

When my machine is Danish, **ii** equals null and **jj** returns an exception ("Object reference not set to an instance of an object") but, interestingly, **_DsAttribute** has the same data as when my machine is English (US-English). Also, when I search for the value of **DtgFields.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("AttributeID").Value**, I can find it in the data from **_DsAttribute**. The data for the ID is, at least to the naked eye, the same.

How do I make use of CultureInfo to avoid this sort of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim ii = _DsAttribute.Tables(0).Rows.Find(New Guid(DtgFields.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("AttributeID").Value.ToString))
Dim jj = _DsAttribute.Tables(0).Rows.Find(New Guid(DtgFields.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("AttributeID").Value.ToString)).Item("Checked")
```

The above was the solution, for me. Hans' answer has lots of technical information that was very helpful (thus my upvote) and lead me to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is *technically* possible, Danish uses a different sort order than US-English.  You'll find Mr Åårdvårk at the beginning of the phone book in Denmark, not at the end as in the USA.

That makes string comparison a dangerous proposition if the Find() method uses binary search or a tree to locate the data.  Which is certainly the case for DataSet, its primary key index is a red-black tree.  What goes wrong is that the algorithm follows the wrong path down the tree when the index was written with Danish as the collation but is read with English as the collation.  Or the other way around.  The result is that it can't find an entry in the tree, even though it exists.

Contra-indications is that a dbase column of type Guid should never be a string, although it is not uncommon that it is.  And that Guid values should not contain characters that can steer the search wrong.  Maybe the column isn't clean and contains other, non-guid values.  You fix it by changing the column type or by using the same collation order (i.e. language) consistently.  Try CultureInfo.CurrentCulture for a possible quick fix.

Comment: The quick fix doesn't work and the field where the GUIDs are stored is a uniqueidentifier field. One test, so far, shows that if I use the string I get from the db to create a new GUID and use that to feed into the Find() it works.